# Highcharts Line Chart does not fit data into all of categories

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts

Highcharts seems to create numbers that are not inside categories. Is there a way to auto-adjust data to fit into the categories.

```
this.options = {
            chart: {
            type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Line Test Chart'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
      stackLabels: { enabled: true}
    },
    tooltip: {
             headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
             pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}'
            },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
          stacking: 'normal',
           grouping: false,
          dataLabels: {enabled: true},
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Construction--Spending Non-Residential',
        data: [100, 99, 98, 99, 99, 100, 99, 97, 98, 99, 100, 99, 97, 99, 98, 99]
            },{
        name: 'Construction--Spending Residential',
        data: [100, 98, 99, 97, 96, 98, 100, 97, 98, 96, 98, 97, 98, 100, 98, 97]
            }]
        };
    }
    options: Object;
```

**See:** [Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/wNmkPESpfXKWftrwsQfA?p=preview)

**Image Example of what I am trying to achieve**:
 [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6w9Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

It happens, because in your case you have more points that categories defined in the categories array and `pointInterval` is equal 1. You can for example change xAxis type to 'datetime' and set different `pointInterval` (e.g. 6 months) but it is up to you how you arrange your data.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointStart
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointInterval

Example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/KBDyCQsEPXNc3GUtUukr?p=preview